# update previous row sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I want to update previous row based on value with same value others field

let say something like this :

[image]

I want to update an empty cell with previous value from previous record with same date, tr, sh.

I try something like this, but I think not correct

```
UPDATE #temptable
  SET
      tk = b.tk
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           a.datetime,
           a.date,
           a.tr,
           a.sh,
           b.tk
    FROM
    (
        SELECT sh,
               tr,
               date,
               datetime
        FROM #temptable
        WHERE tk = 0
    ) a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT sh,
               tr,
               date,
               datetime,
               tk
        FROM #temptable
        WHERE tk != 0
    ) b ON(a.sh = b.sh
           AND a.tr = b.tr
           AND a.date = b.date
           AND a.datetime >= b.datetime)
) b
WHERE #temptable.tr = b.tr
      AND #temptable.date = b.date
      AND (#temptable.tk = 0
           OR #temptable.tk IS NULL);
```

need your suggestion about this case.
thank you

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected output instead of images .So,that people can help you out.Many of the user's won't have the access to open the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CTE` to check first and update the values. I assume u have multiple rows to be updated

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (DATETIME DATETIME, DATE DATE, tr INT, sh INT, tk VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @temp (DATETIME, DATE, tr, sh, tk)
SELECT '2018-02-06 00:00:00', '2018-02-06', 447, 2144, '10000001'

UNION ALL

SELECT '2018-02-06 00:00:00', '2018-02-06', 447, 2144, '';

WITH Opt
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @temp t
    WHERE t.tk = '' AND EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM @temp x
            WHERE cast(x.DATETIME AS DATE) = cast(t.DATETIME AS DATE) AND x.DATE = t.DATE AND x.tr = t.tr AND x.sh = t.sh AND x.tk <> t.tk
            )
    )
UPDATE Opt
SET tk = t.tk
FROM opt x
INNER JOIN @temp t
    ON cast(x.DATETIME AS DATE) = cast(t.DATETIME AS DATE) AND x.DATE = t.DATE AND x.tr = t.tr AND x.sh = t.sh AND x.tk <> t.tk

SELECT *
FROM @temp
```

Answer (score 1):

LAG can be used for this.

```
update #temptable set tk = b.tk
from (select a.datetime,
           a.date,
           a.tr,
           a.sh,
           ISNULL(LAG(tk) OVER(PARTITION BY d, t, tr, sh ORDER BY d, t, tr, sh) , tk) tk
from #temptable a) b
```

I made a testtable containing the two rows in your example and that part worked for me. Let me know if you are having further issues

Comment: hi @Zulatin this is not worked for me, it just switch value, sorry for late response

Comment: If you give me more data to work with, ill update my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE #temptable AS R INNER JOIN #temptable AS P ON R.date= P.date
 AND R.TR = P.TR AND R.SH = P.SH AND P.TK != '' SET R.tk = P.tk WHERE R.tk = ''
```

Try to use update inner join